# PHP Shuffle - Impressions Count

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics

I use PHP shuffle to show 3 versions of 1 page.

I want to know how equaly are these 3 vesions diplayed, how many of each version is displayed, are they displayed equally

So what I'm looking for is

**A:** insight onto how many (%) PHP shuffle shows differenet versions

**or B:**

Short impressions counter script for each version.

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Comment: Seeing some code might help

Comment: If you are using Google Analytics you could push an event so you can track which page is displayed, or you could use their Experiments to do this and instead of randomizing the page you set it up so that GA chooses 1 of the 3

Comment: @cmorrissey - I was looking into using GA, but could not figure out how to do it. Events tracks cliks or actions ... How can I track rotating banner impressions with GA? I also wanted to trak modal popup impressions and ran into same problem.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events